# What is the size of Ubuntu repository?

Tags: repository

I would like to know the total size of Ubuntu repository with individual repository-component (Main, Universe, Multiverse, Restricted)  sizes for:

- 32-bit platform.
- 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I just installed [apt-mirror](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/apt-mirror) [image: Install apt-mirror]
 and configured it to mirror maverick,  maverick-security, and   maverick-updates (i386 only). It reported:

`68.6 GiB will be downloaded into archive.`

Comment: I am thinking of starting a project where I am going to convert all the existing apt packages on the Ubuntu repositories to snappy versions on my server

Answer (score 1):

When I downloaded it in March 2011, everything in all, both 32 and 64 bit (from lucid to maverick) archive.ubuntulinux.org combined with source packs = ~450-500GB. Hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: 445GB 515,975 files... That's a lot. Mind you that was from last year. I estimate that it is probably a bit larger considering the new releases. I will probably have to get a 1 to 2 terabyte dedicated hard drive to fit the new repository.

Comment: its a lot, but it includes source codes. the pure compiled list is 10x less ~=60gb