# Ubuntu: Where to download ubuntu repository

Tags: 11.10, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I have installed the ubuntu 11.10 on my PC but unfortunately my internet connection is not working there now i was wondering if i could download all the repository on some other window machine. and later i could install that repository to my ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sure that this is doable, but maybe it is overkill (you will have to download around 70 Gb, check http://askubuntu.com/questions/21605/what-is-the-size-of-ubuntu-repository). Check this question, it could be a better solution for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/84323/25863) on the other question should allow you to understand how to do download the files in a Windows computer and create your own repository in your Ubuntu computer. I have closed this question.