# 16.04: Create "deb" with all repositories for offline installation

Tags: 16.04, offline

I successfully installed 16.04 desktop on a PC **without internet** from DVD.

Then I had to install a 3rd party software that requires extra ubuntu packages. 
This installation failed.

Can you please tell how can I create a package file (no matter its size) that is "All included" ?

When I install Centos I do not have such problem .
The DVD contains all packages.

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: If you have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/21605/what-is-the-size-of-ubuntu-repository  you'll note it about 450-500GB in size back in 2011 (x86 & x86_64 only); CentOS has far fewer packages so it's far smaller, but "*All included*" is a little larger than most thumb-drives.

Comment: Thank you very much.