# size of mirror repositories

Tags: repository, mirrors

I'm getting ubuntu with the folowing command:

```
rsync -a --progress rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /home/ubuntu
```

It downloaded 1.2T and download is not finished.

My Data is:

```
root@repo:/home/ubuntu# ls 
dists  indices  ls-lR.gz  pool  project  ubuntu
root@repo:/home/ubuntu# ls ubuntu/dists/
bionic        bionic-updates   devel-security   focal-proposed  jammy-backports  kinetic        kinetic-updates  lunar-security    trusty-proposed  xenial-backports
bionic-backports  devel        devel-updates    focal-security  jammy-proposed   kinetic-backports  lunar        lunar-updates     trusty-security  xenial-proposed
bionic-proposed   devel-backports  focal        focal-updates   jammy-security   kinetic-proposed   lunar-backports  trusty        trusty-updates   xenial-security
bionic-security   devel-proposed   focal-backports  jammy       jammy-updates    kinetic-security   lunar-proposed   trusty-backports  xenial       xenial-updates
```

What's size of total repositories?

Comment: Why are you downloading the entire repository tree for all distributions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of Ubuntu repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21605/what-is-the-size-of-ubuntu-repository)

Comment: Seems it could use an update, since the latest answers are more than 10 years old. And it seems we can conclude that the size is  > 1.2 TB. 

Comment: I recall discussion somewhere somewhat recently (*in terms of cycles; jammy, or kinetic maybe; currently we're in lunar with regards how I think of time*) where a size exploration was performed (*moving storage maybe; I can't recall why*), but I had no reason to care or recall what it was, thus took no notice... But I do concur @ArturMeinild

Comment: @ArturMeinild We want to become a mirror.

Comment: I guess you'll then find out when it's finished - and it would be a nice gesture to update [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21605/what-is-the-size-of-ubuntu-repository). 

Comment: @ArturMeinild the updated answer can be posted to that question, we don't need another question for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the last time I checked, which was in the 20.04 cycle, the total size of all the current repositories available to be mirrored from the standard archive repos is somewhere upwards of 2TB of space.  I don't have an exact value, as I haven't asked the mirrors team lately, but that value is *just* for `amd64` and `i386` and **does not** include the Ports mirrors which handle non-standard arches like ARM and such.

---

**Edit - January 4, 2022** Using `rsync -h --recursive -n --stats rsync://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` has yielded the current size *as of this edit* of the repositories as follows, **in total**:

```
Total file size: 2.10T bytes
```

So currently, the size of the repositories **for `i386` and `amd64` architectures** currently is in excess of 2.1TB - so you will need lots of storage space AND space for expansion - so I'd recommend at *least* 4TB of available storage if you intend to be a long term mirror.

I am unable to find the current size of the `ports` repositories (for ARM and such) but I would expect it to be at least double what we see for the main `i386` and `amd64` repositories because of so many additional things that ports has in it for architectures.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (2023-05-20), the size of ubuntu-ports, ubuntu archive, cdimage, and releases are:

| module name | size |
| --- | --- |
| /ubuntu-ports | 2.5 TB |
| /ubuntu | 2.1 TB |
| /ubuntu-cdimage | 410.2 GB |
| /ubuntu-releases | 36.4 GB |

(I'm the maintainer of https://ftp.ubuntu-tw.org and https://mirror.ossplanet.net , just did a `du -sh` yesterday.)